# Scheduled Apex Class Testing Issue

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, json, deserialize

I am trying to test a scheduled class in apex, but upon running the test method it gives me the following error:

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('0' (code 48)): was
>   expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:4]
>
> Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1
>   Class.retrieveGAdata.main: line 18, column 1
>   Class.scheduledGoogleAnalytics.execute: line 4, column 1

This is my test method:

```
 public static testMethod void testscheduledGA()
      {
          Test.startTest();

          scheduledGoogleAnalytics sga = new  scheduledGoogleAnalytics(); 
          String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?'; 
          system.schedule('Test GA check', sch, sga);

          Test.stopTest();


  }
```

This is my scheduled class:

```
global class scheduledGoogleAnalytics implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      retrieveGAdata ga = new  retrieveGAdata(); 
      ga.main();
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is line 18 from retrieveGAdata:

```
 JsonGA data = (JsonGA) JSON.deserialize(s, JsonGA.class);
```

where s is a string response;

Comment: I am pretty sure that issues is in string "s" -- that is not valid json

Comment: if I run retrieveGAdata everything works perfectly fine, and s is a callout response so it is a valid json. I am just wondering when I am running the test class maybe s doesn't get any response

Comment: yes SF don't make real callout in test classes. You need to handle that. Use mock callout and then pass valid JSON.

Comment: yeah I was having some issues with mock callouts so I just added some bypassing test conditions in my code, but I guess I forgot to handle the json response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the fact that I was not giving a proper json response when the test class was triggered. Adding a mock return json statement helped me solve the problem.